# ThreeJS PointMaterial texture transparent background issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a set of particles made with THREE.Points, and I'm using THREE.PointMaterial with texture. The texture are stroke rectangles made with canvas, and it works, but just partially, that is the problem.

Here you can see what is happening with my particles:

[image]

As you can see, the transparency of the particles work just with some particles and with some others do not.

What could be happening here?

This is the code I use to create the material:

```
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {
  size: this.particleSize,
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
  map: ct.getTexture(),
  transparent: true,
  fog: false } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your problem is the particles are not sorted by depth and rendered in back-to-front order.

The solution is to add

```
material.alphaTest = 0.5;
```

Then, transparent fragments will be discarded.

three.js r.73

Comment: Thanks WestLangley.!

 I applied this solution and it works!. 
But just to be sure I'm understanding what I did, this alphaTest property is working as an threshold that set every pixel of the used texture that has an alpha value over .5 (in this case) as transparent, and those with a value less  than .5 as an opaque pixel ??
Thanks Again

Comment: Not quite. For alpha values less than 0.5, the fragment is discarded. In particular, the depth buffer is not written to.